# Make it into Danish time - it does not work the way I want it straight pt

Tags: php, date

I have tried to make my time on the Danish time, but it does not work quite as I'd like it.

```
<?php echo date("d/m/Y - H:s", $online_sidste);?>
```

I just would like it to look like this: 15/10-2013 - 08:01

i have complete this her:

```
date("d/m-Y - H:i", strtotime($online_sidste));
```

Comment: So just use `echo date("d/m-Y - H:s", $online_sidste);` instead? What's the expected result and how is it different from what you currently have?

Comment: @AmalMurali I feel like I've been here

Comment: What does `var_dump($online_sidste);` output?

Comment: @AmalMurali 

`string(19) "2013-10-14 22:18:30"` its coming output now :)

Comment: ohhh sorry, I understand not just your first question, but I understand it perfectly fine now. @AmalMurali

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo date_create($online_sidste)->format('d/m-Y - H:i');
```

or

```
date("d/m-Y - H:i", strtotime($online_sidste));
```

Answer (score 1):

just format it

```
$today = date("d/m-Y - H:s");
echo $today;
```

Comment: Well it is **$online_sidste** should I have turned into Danish time